# select box value changes on form reloading with php validation

Tags: php, html

I need a solution for this. Here I want to validate form elements. I did it with PHP but what my problem is on clicking submit button validation process takes place but **select box value changes to select dept**.
FOR EXAMPLE, if you just click submit button without giving student `id` by only `select dept..` the message shows enter `studentid` but select box value changes to `select dept` again as it page reloads first..

php:

```
if($_POST['submit']!='')
{
    $c=0;
    if($_POST['studid']=='' ) {
        $msg_id="Enter stud id";
        $c++;
    }
    if($_POST[studdept]=='') {
        $msg_dept="Enter stud dept";
        $c++;
    }
    if($c==0) {
        echo "form has been submitted..";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form id="myform" action="" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td> Studid: *</td> <td> <input type="text" name="studid" maxlength="10" value="<?=$_POST[studid]?>"> </td> <td> <?php echo $msg_id; ?> </td> </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> StudDept: *</td>
            <td>
                <select name="studdept">
                    <option value="" selected="selected" >select dept</option>
                    <option value="cse" >cse</option>
                    <option value="eee" >eee</option>
                    <option value="mech" >mech</option>
                    <option value="ece" >ece</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $msg_dept; ?> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

can someone help me here?

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to generate your `<option></option>` list through loop (if you're generating Department list from Database Table) where you have to put condition which you had put it for first `<option>` pair.

Or You can put a Turnary Operator (if you're using static list).

```
<select name="studdept">
    <option value="none" <?php echo ($_REQUEST['studdept']=='none'?'selected="selected"'):'';?> >select dept</option>
    <option value="cse" <?php echo ($_REQUEST['studdept']=='cse'?'selected="selected"'):'';?> >cse</option>
    <option value="eee" <?php echo ($_REQUEST['studdept']=='eee'?'selected="selected"'):'';?> >eee</option>    
    <option value="mech" <?php echo ($_REQUEST['studdept']=='mech'?'selected="selected"'):'';?> >mech</option>
    <option value="ece" <?php echo ($_REQUEST['studdept']=='ece'?'selected="selected"');:''?> >ece</option>
</select>
```

And use `$_REQUEST` instead `$_GET` or `$_POST`.

Comment: thanks for ur kind reply ,. can u explain somemore how i have to use loops here?

Comment: thanks for your explained code.it works.. then is there any other way simply to write code than giving ternary operator to every option tag!

Answer (score 0):

The method of your form is **POST** and you are trying to get the department using **GET**  `<? echo ($_GET['studdept'] == 'cse' ? 'selected="selected"' : '') ?>`.

Anyway, you'll need to improve your HTML so you check if any of the deptartments are selected (not just 'cse'). A for/while loop will do the job.

In addition, I would add `" "` to the post variables, as you did in `if($_POST['studid']=='' )` (but you didn't in `if($_POST[studdept]=='')`)

Comment: @user2720205 you have good info in **[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp)** or in the **[PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php)**. If I have more time, I'll edit my post to show you an example with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your specifies that the form data will be submitted using the POST method.

The way that PHP does this is to store all the "posted" values into an associative array called "$_POST".
Be sure to take notice the names of the form data names, as they represent the keys in the "$_POST" associative array.

Use: `$_POST['studdept']` instead of: `$_GET['studdept']`

Answer (score 0):

Beacause you use method `POST` for send data and you are trying to get value using `$_GET['studdept']`.

so you have two ways:

(1) just change the method to `GET` or
 (2) change `$_GET['studdept']` to `$_POST['studdept']`.

Comment: remove `selected="selected"` from the option box.and what are you trying to do.i select `cse` then cse is select or what?explain.

Comment: thanks for spending ur time,. i not only need cse dept.. i want my select box value to be unchanged after clicking submit button with validation